# Trying to pass to the second page of questions tagged with a tag clears the tag

Tags: bug, tags, questions

I am trying to see all the questions tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), but when I pass to the second page, the tag is removed from the search.

> [image: screenshot]

As result, the list contains also questions that aren't about Python.

> [image: screenshot]

If this makes any difference, it happens on Google Chrome 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit) running on openSUSE Tumbleweed. I have yet to try with the same browser running on Windows 10.

Comment: I get the same on Windows 10 with Google Chrome 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit).